# Changes are not being deployed to AWS console

Tags: python, command-line-interface, aws-cdk

I am deploying changes to AWS console throuhg the command

```
cdk deploy --all
```

Previously it worked well and created the stack on AWS console but now after creating another stack when I tried to run the same command `cdk deploy all` rather than deploying code to AWS it shows just following four statements

```
Usage:
  cdk [-vbo] [--toc] [--notransition] [--logo=<logo>] [--theme=<theme>] [--custom-css=<cssfile>] FILE
  cdk --install-theme=<theme>
  cdk --default-theme=<theme>
  cdk --generate=<name>
```

Comment: is your cdk directory correct?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra yes it is, nothing changed

Comment: what are the output of `cdk diff`, `cdk synth`

Comment: @JatinMehrotra same 4 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something changed in your environment and now `cdk` is pointing to the [`Courseware Development Kit`](https://Courseware%20Development%20Kit) instead of the `aws-cdk`.

You can confirm this by studying the output of `which cdk`.

To fix this, uninstall `Courseware Development Kit` or create a shell alias for it (after putting it further down in your `$PATH`).

Also, `cdk deploy all` is not the right command - you're looking for `cdk deploy --all`.